# JSON post using jQuery is working fine with FF, Chrome & Safari but does not work in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have to **Post Email and Password** to my REST Service and it is hosted on different domain and i have allowed cross domain origin to * for access any cross domain request. and this is
**Working fine**

- with FF 16
- Chrome 22
- Safari 5

  but **it is not working in IE 8.0**

I have tried several approach to resolve but still i m looking for solution.

```
<input type="button" value="POST" onclick="postData();" />

//Call authorization process
function postData() {
    var url = 'http://www.mydomain.com/authorize';
    var data = { 'email': 'myemail@gmail.com', 'password': 'mypassword' };
    jQuery.post(url, data, authorizeCallback, 'json');
}
jQuery.extend({
    post: function (url, data, callback, type, errorcallback) {
        return _ajax_request(url, data, callback, type, 'POST', errorcallback);
    }
});
function _ajax_request(url, data, callback, type, method, errorcallback) {
    if (typeof errorcallback == 'undefined') errorcallback = defaulterrordisplay;
    return jQuery.ajax({
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: callback,
        dataType: type,
        error: errorcallback
    });
}

 //Callback from authorization process
function authorizeCallback(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
/*Here i am getting Message :  'Invalid email or password' only for IE,
otherwise it will return Message : "OK" with Authorization ID and Token
*/
}
```

**Note:** i am using pure HTML no server technology are used. and everything are working fine with all browsers except IE8.

Seeking for your best answer and suggestion for the same.

Thanks and Regards,

Imdadhusen

Comment: Thanks for your comment. What changes should be done on serve side?

Comment: you can use jersy library in case the server is java based and return a jsonp response

Answer (score -1):

Did you say you are getting "Invalid email or password". This makes me think that you should debug the server code on http://www.mydomain.com/authorize.